# How to download xcode .dmg file on windows for install on another computer?

Tags: ios, xcode, windows, macos, app-store

I've recently been given a project at work that I need OSX to work on. I was given a brand new mac mini for the project but it's brand new and doesn't have xcode. Downloading at work is super slow and would take days but at home I have much better speeds but I don't have a mac. How can I download the .dmg file using my Windows machine so that I can take it to work and put it on my computer there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the Xcode install dmg (and additional tools like the recommended "Command Line Tools" from the [Apple Developer Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) page.

Just sign in with your developer Apple ID when it prompts you (If you don't have one, make a free one by clicking create on the above site. Try using the same Apple ID as the one you use on your new Mac) and find and download the latest Xcode (Xcode 7.2 as of writing) in the download list:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd try just downloading the .dmg archive file from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/) and saving to a USB drive that is formatted/readable from both platforms.